# How to merge two node server files?

Tags: node.js, express, linphone

I am working on node.js. I have two servers one for my own node base application and one is for VOIP linphone web node based application. 
I want to merge both of the servers and want to run on the same port but there are some issues my own application server requires "HTTP" but the linphone server requires "express" libraries.

**My Own Application Node Server Code**

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");

var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/jpeg",
    "png": "image/png",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"
};

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

//uri = "www/" + uri;

if (uri.charAt(uri.length - 1) == "/") {
    uri += "index.html";
}

if (uri.indexOf("..") != -1) {
    response.writeHead(403);
    response.end();
}

var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

console.log("\tAttempting to serve: " + filename);

fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {

    if (!exists) {
        console.log("File not found: " + filename);
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end("Sorry, the file you requested was not found. Don't let it ruin your day! :)");
        return;
    }

    var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename).split(".")[1]];
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});

    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    fileStream.pipe(response);
});

}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

console.log('listening on ' + (process.env.PORT || 8080));
```

**Linphone Web App Node Server File Code**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var commander = require('commander');
    var https = require('https');
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var app = express();

    commander
    .version('0.0.1')
    .option('-d, --debug', 'Debug env')
    .option('-p, --port <n>', 'HTTP port', parseInt)
    .parse(process.argv);

    app.set('port', commander.port ? commander.port : 8888);
    app.set('env', commander.debug ? 'debug' : 'release');
    app.set('tmp', __dirname + '/tmp/');
    app.set('public', __dirname + '/core/');
    app.set('tmp', app.get('public') + '/tmp/');
    app.set('expires', (app.get('env') === 'debug') ? 0 : 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 * 1000);

    app.configure(function() {
        app.use(express.compress());
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.static(app.get('public'), {maxAge: app.get('expires')}));
    });

    fs.mkdir(app.get('tmp'), 0777, function(err) {
    });

    function my_random() {
        var current_date = (new Date()).valueOf().toString();
        var random = Math.random().toString();
        return crypto.createHash('sha1').update(current_date + random).digest('hex');
    }

    app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
        data = req.body.data.replace(/ /g, '+');
        filename = app.get('tmp') + "/" + my_random();
        console.log("Upload(" + req.body.filename + ", " + data.length + "): " + filename);
fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'base64', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Forbidden \n');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Ok \n');
        console.log("The file \"" + filename + "\" was saved!");
    }
    });
    });

    module.exports = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port') + ' env ' + app.get('env'));
    });
```

Comment: are you planning to mount both servers on the same domain?

Comment: yes i want to merge the both servers as a single application and want to use their functionality over a single port or domain such as htpp://localhost:8080

Comment: Given how small your app is, I'd just tweak it to use express also.

Comment: @user3726040 and you want to keep the command line functionality of the linphone web app?

Comment: i just want to merge both of the servers on the same port.please help me out of this problem.